# Draw a ASCII-art Christmas tree in C++

Tags: c++, function

I want to draw a ASCII-art Christmas tree in C++ using functions with parameters.

This is what I have got so far, which works for the most part however when drawing the actual body of the tree (leaves) it seems to repeat it multiple times.

This effect seems to increase as the height of the tree does as well. So for example if a height of 4 is entered for the tree then the body will be drawn 2 times. if the height is 5, then it is drawn 3 times. 6 is 4 times and so on.

Any help?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char BLANK = ' ';     
const char LEAF = '#';      
const char WOOD = '|';      

void drawAXmasTree();
void drawFoliage(int);
void drawTrunk(int);
void getValidHeight(int&);
void drawALineOfFoliage(int, int);

int main()
{
    cout << "Due on 11 December 2018 \n\n";
    drawAXmasTree();
}

void drawAXmasTree()
{
    int treeHeight = 0;

    getValidHeight(treeHeight); //read in a valid value for the tree height
    drawFoliage(treeHeight);            //draw tree foliage
    drawTrunk(treeHeight);          //draw tree trunk
}

void drawFoliage(int trHgt) //draw the foliage
{
    int branchLine = 1;
    int treeHeight = trHgt;

    while (branchLine <= (trHgt - 2))
    {
        drawALineOfFoliage(treeHeight, branchLine); 
        branchLine += 1;
    }
}

void drawTrunk(int trHgt)   //draw the trunk
{
    int trunkLine = 1;
    int spaces;

    while (trunkLine <= 2)  // for each line in the truck
    {
        spaces = 1;

        while (spaces <= (trHgt - 2))   //draw the spaces on the left
        {
            cout << BLANK;
            spaces += 1;
        }

        cout << WOOD;       //draw the truck
        cout << endl;           //go to next line
        trunkLine += 1;
    }
}

void getValidHeight(int& trHgt)
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the size of the tree(4 - 20): ";
        cin >> trHgt;
        if (trHgt < 4 || trHgt > 20)
        {
            cout << "ERROR: Invalid height! ";
        }
    } 
    while (trHgt < 4 || trHgt > 20);
}

void drawALineOfFoliage(int trHgt, int brLine)
{
    int treeHeight = trHgt;
    int branchLine = brLine;
    int spaces = trHgt - 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < (treeHeight - 2); i++) {
        for (int j = spaces; j > 0; j--)
        {
            cout << BLANK;
        }
        for (int foliage = 0; foliage <= i * 2; foliage++)
        {
            cout << LEAF;
        }
        spaces--;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Talk about time locality! Welcome to Stackoverflow Tom! :) Tip: Where to you use this variable `int branchLine = brLine;`?

Comment: Probably because "drawALine..." doesn't draw **a** line like it says; it draws `treeHeight - 2` lines.

Comment: Step through your code with a visual debugger

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is the following:

In the function `drawFoliage` you intended to loop and call `drawALineOfFoliage` for each line. But you actually draw the whole tree every time you call `drawALineOfFoliage`.

In order to fix you code, just replace `drawFoliage` for `drawALineOfFoliage` in the `drawAXMasTree` function, like this:

```
void drawAXmasTree()
{
    int treeHeight = 0;

    getValidHeight(treeHeight); //read in a valid value for the tree height
    drawALineOfFoliage(treeHeight); 
    drawTrunk(treeHeight);          
}
```

**Notice you don't need the second argument in `drawALineOfFoliage` since you don't actually use it.**

As for `drawFoliage`, you can just erase it.

Comment: I would do that, but the pseudocode that this is based on requires me to have all the functions that are there, thanks anyway.

Comment: Then you can just remove the outermost loop in drawALineOfFoliage, as you are already doing it in drawFoliage.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I managed to resolve this because like people said it was drawing the whole tree rather than just one line. All I had to do was change the drawALineOfFoliage function to the following;

```
void drawALineOfFoliage(int trHgt, int brLine)
{
    int treeHeight = trHgt;
    int branchLine = brLine - 1;
    int spaces = trHgt - 2;

    for (int i = spaces; i > branchLine; i--)
    {
        cout << BLANK;
    }
    for (int foliage = 0; foliage <= branchLine * 2; foliage++)
    {
        cout << LEAF;
    }
    spaces--;
    cout << endl;   
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at your spaces variables, since it doesn't do anything.
You should get it as an argument from drawFoliage or use a static variable as shown here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-cpp/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    const char BLANK = ' ';
    const char LEAF = '#';
    const char WOOD = '|';

    void drawAXmasTree();
    void drawFoliage(int);
    void drawTrunk(int);
    void getValidHeight(int&);
    void drawALineOfFoliage(int, int);

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Due on 11 December 2018 \n\n";
        drawAXmasTree();

        system("pause");
    }

    void drawAXmasTree()
    {
        int treeHeight = 0;

        getValidHeight(treeHeight); 
        drawFoliage(treeHeight);             
        drawTrunk(treeHeight);          
    }

    void drawFoliage(int trHgt) 
    {
        int branchLine = 1;
        int treeHeight = trHgt;

        while (branchLine <= (trHgt - 2))
        {
            drawALineOfFoliage(treeHeight, branchLine);
            branchLine += 1;
        }
    }

    void drawTrunk(int trHgt)   
    {
        int trunkLine = 1;
        int spaces;

        for (trunkLine; trunkLine <= 2; trunkLine++)
        {
            for (spaces = 1; spaces <= (trHgt - 1); spaces++)
            {
                cout << BLANK;
            }
            cout << WOOD;
            cout << "\n";

        }
    }

    void getValidHeight(int& trHgt)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Enter the size of the tree(4 - 20): ";
            cin >> trHgt;
            if (trHgt < 4 || trHgt > 20)
            {
                cout << "ERROR: Invalid height! ";
            }
        } while (trHgt < 4 || trHgt > 20);
    }

    void drawALineOfFoliage(int trHgt, int brLine)
    {
        int treeHeight = trHgt;
        int branchLine = brLine;
        int spaces(0);
        int tree(0);

        for (spaces; spaces < (trHgt - branchLine); spaces++)
        {
            cout << BLANK;
        }
        for (tree; tree < (branchLine * 2 - 1); tree++)
        {
            cout << LEAF;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```